# How to add H4 tag to the_content filter (after content)?

Tags: title, the-content

I would like the H4 title to display before the loop starts and only once.

The problem I'm having is that H4 tag title I've created either gets stuck in the loop or it displays on the top of the post, before the content, which is what I do not want.

This is what I have.

```
//Related stock photo function
function custom_content_after_post($content){
    if (get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'portfolio') {

        //Query for the the related posts - portfolio custom post type
        $loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand'));
        $sptitle = '<h4>Related Stock Photos</h4>';

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            $loop->the_post();

            $content .= '<div style="margin:25px 10px 0px 10px;">';
            $content .= '<ul style="list-style-type:none;">';
            $content .= '<li style="display:inline;float:left;">';              
            //Display post thumbnail assigned to it.
            $content .= '<div style="margin:25px 10px 0px 10px;">';
            $content .= '<a href="' .get_permalink(). '" >' .get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'). '</a>';
            $content .= '<p><strong><a href="' .get_permalink(). '" >' . get_the_title() . '</a></strong></p>';                 
            $content .= '</li>';
            $content .= '</ul>';
            $content .= '</div>';
        }
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_content_after_post' );
```

Comment: Do you mean the `<h4` tag?

Comment: yeah, sorry, I meant h4 tag.

Comment: One of your `div` tags is not being closed, you open two but only close one.

Comment: @t31los thanks for the heads up! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
   //Related stock photo function
   function custom_content_after_post($content){
    if (get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'portfolio') {

    //Query for the the related posts - portfolio custom post type
    $loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand'));
    $sptitle = '<h4>Related Stock Photos</h4>';

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();

        $div  = '<div style="margin:25px 10px 0px 10px;">';
        $div .= '<ul style="list-style-type:none;">';
        $div .= '<li style="display:inline;float:left;">';              
        //Display post thumbnail assigned to it.
        $div .= '<div style="margin:25px 10px 0px 10px;">';
        $div .= '<a href="' .get_permalink(). '" >' .get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'). '</a>';
        $div .= '<p><strong><a href="' .get_permalink(). '" >' . get_the_title() . '</a></strong></p>';  
        $div .= '</div>';               
        $div .= '</li>';
        $div .= '</ul>';
        $div .= '</div>';

    }

 }

 return $content .$sptitle .$div;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_content_after_post' );
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I added return $content .$sptitle .$div; and that displayed the H tag once before the query loop.

Comment: That worked perfect! See here http://www.pixelgrunt.com/stock-photo/zebra-stock-photo

Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome mark it as resolved.

Comment: Same comment here, you open two `div` tags and close only one. Whilst it may work, it's invalid markup.

Comment: True, I did not make any attention to that. I was focused on filter. I'm editing